# difference between object code and embeded code?

Tags: asp.net

i have a doubt difference between object code  and embeded code  .
 thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is like you comparing apples and episodes of startrek, embedded code means that is code nested inside some other code for instance javascript in HTML, Object code is code of Object Oriented programming language. 
Note: It can also refer to the code that is not readable for humans, so machine code for instance. Even though I haven heard someone, but copyright lawyers, calling it that way for very long time :).

Answer (score 1):

[Object code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Code) is a term referring to source code which has been compiled into binary machine code, but has not been linked to produce a runnable executable.

Embedded code just means code that's inside something else. The other connotation is *embedded development*, which refers to developing software for [embedded devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_Devices).

Neither of these mean much in the context of ASP.NET. Perhaps you should rephrase your question?